# Spring webflux - Asynchronos operation

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using Spring webflux and the requirement is to return the REST call with the response 202 and process the request asynchronously in the backend.

Here is my code.

**Router,**

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> startJob() {
        return route(POST("/api/v1/service/job").and(
                    accept(APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    handler::startJob);
    }
```

**Handler,**

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> startJob(final ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(JobDto.class)
                      .flatMap(req -> {
                          Mono.defer(() -> runJobs(req)).subscribe();
                          return ServerResponse.accepted().build();
                      });
    }


private Mono<String> runJobs(final JobDto req) {
        return jobRepo.fetchJobs(req).collectList()
                               .zipWhen((jobs) -> Flux.fromIterable(jobs)
                                                        .flatMap((job) -> runJob(req, job)).collectList())
                               .flatMap(response -> {
                                   return Mono.just(req.getJobName());
                               });
    }
```

Is this the right approach? Is there any better approach?

Comment: "Is there any better approach?" Yes, remove all that. It's the Reactive  Framework's job to handle things in the background. This just undoes all that. If you want to do this use the `Servlet` API.

Comment: Servlet is not an options. The background job takes about 10 mins to complete and I don’t want the caller to wait. The call should be returned and process the job in the backend.

Comment: Looks like my approach is a good approach.

Comment: Instead of calling subscribe in flatMap, you can use `map` to create `accepted` response and use `doOnNext` to call `runJobs(req).subscribe()`

Comment: @AdemÇırak request.bodyToMono(JobDto.class).map(req -> ServerResponse.accepted().build())
        .doOnNext(req -> runJobs(req).subscribe()). How to pass the JobDto obejct to runJobs here. I get only ServerResponse in doOnNext.

Comment: 10 minutes eh? The old moving requirements trick. Anyway, if you really want to know, look at [4.5. Threading and Schedulers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers), but I recommend you start reading the fine manual from the beginning.

Comment: If you chain doOnNext before map operation you can access req. 
Something like this: request.bodyToMono(JobDto.class).doOnNext(req -> runJobs(req).subscribe()).map(req -> ServerResponse.accepted().build())

Comment: If you want to be fail-safe, I would recommend to publish long running task to queue and consume from the queue. 10 min. very long time your server can go down and your long running job can disappear.